# What will be returned when the JSON path is not present inside JSON?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonpath

We have following JSON:-

```
def json='''{
"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": {
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
       }
   }
}'''
```

To check whether path is present inside JSON, I am using com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath [Refer for more](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Below are the code, I am using:-

```
import groovy.json.*
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria.where;
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter.filter;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JacksonMappingProvider

def path = "\$.widget.image.src"
def value = parse(json).read(path).toString()
log.info value
```

Since, the "path" is present inside JSON.. So it will return the value as "Images/Sun.png", What if this path not present inside JSON:-

Have a look at this code:-

```
 def path = "\$.widget.image.src1"
 def value = parse(json).read(path).toString()
 log.info value
```

It is giving error as :-

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException : no results for path: $['widget']['image']['src1']
```

But now, I have many path to be validated, and if path doesn't match, it will be failed in the middle of the script and rest of the path will not be validated.. How to handle this thing using groovy?

if I am using if/else, and passing as NULL.. it is not getting validated, And the script fails at that step.

Comment: Are you asking us how to catch exceptions in groovy? http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_exception_handling

Comment: Yes, kind of. Since the error, which I am getting comes as a dialog box.. if it prints something in the logs like "path not present", then we can handle it using if else

Comment: @JBNizet - Hey thanks, Using try catch, it worked,.

Answer (score 0):

Using try/catch and final keyword of groovy, we can handle this things.

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as a null, changing your configuration

```
def path = "\$.widget.image.src1"
def value = parse(json).using(Configuration.builder()
              .options(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).build())
              .read(path).toString()
log.info value
```